# EF Core Navigation Property Include uses Left Join instead of Inner Join

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my API project, I have

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public TeamSettings TeamSettings { get; set; }
}

public class TeamSettings
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("TeamSettingsId")]
    public long Id { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public long TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Team Team { set; get; }
}
```

When I use

```
var team = await TeamRepo.GetAsync(t => t.Id == teamId, includes);
```

I can see on my SQL Server Profiler a left join rather than an inner join.

I tried removing the annotations and going for fluent like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
                    .HasOne(t => t.TeamSettings)
                    .WithOne(ts => ts.Team)
                    .HasForeignKey<TeamSettings>(ts => ts.TeamId);
```

But still, all I get is a left join.

Since TeamSettings is created always for any team and is not nullable, shouldn't it be using inner join?

Answer (score 5):

Relational databases cannot enforce one-to-one (i.e. both ends required) relationship, because no standard FK constraint can prevent deleting the dependent record (`TeamSettings` in your case).

Hence EF Core does not support it (`[Required]` attribute on `[Team.TeamSettings]` is ignored). This is sort of explained in the [Required and optional relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships)
 section of the documentation:

> You can use the Fluent API to configure whether the relationship is required or optional. Ultimately this controls whether the **foreign key property is required or optional.**

Since the FK is always at dependent side, technically it means that you can only control whether the dependent can exist w/o a principal. But principal can always exist w/o dependent.

Shortly, relationship dependents are *always* optional, hence the `left join`.

Answer (score 3):

How about a **where clause** "t => t.Id == teamId && t.TeamSettings != null". This should ofcouse be implemented along with the Includes command. This way you force it to behave like an inner join.